# How to add a value to IntentFilter at runtime

Tags: android, maui, azure-ad-msal

I have a maui application with MSAL login, I'm able to do the login on android and ios.But I want to assign the value to the DataScheme at runtime. We are binding this values in pipeline and taking this at runtime for each environment. How can I achieve this .

Here is my code

```
[Activity(Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault },
    DataHost = "auth",
 DataScheme = "msal5564333q2234565")]
public class MsalActivity : BrowserTabActivity
{

}
```

Currently I have hardcoded the Data Scheme. But i want to assign a value at runtime to this.please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

In android, we usually pass data by putting data into Intent.

For example, we can use method `PutExtra` to put data to intent.

```
var secondActivity = new Intent (this, typeof(SecondActivity));

secondActivity.PutExtra ("Data", "SampleData");

StartActivity(secondActivity);
```

Then we can get the passed data by following code:

```
  string text = Intent.GetStringExtra ("Data") ?? "Data not available";
```